# Is C99 support really still not widespread?

Tags: c, compiler-construction, c99

I was reading through some of the best practices for the GNOME project, and one thing that they kept stressing was avoiding C99 features, as support was still not widespread. Some of the things they mentioned were features like single-line comments and declaring variables in the middle of a block. It made me wonder, is C99 support, even for basic features like `//` comments, really still not widespread? It's been almost 15 years now since the standard was adopted, and we've even had a new standard come out in that time. Is this really still an issue?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C99#Implementations

Seems like it still is a bit of an issue, even in GCC, though it looks like some commercial compilers have implemented the entire standard.

Microsoft have said repeatedly there are no plans to implement the C99 standard at any point in the future which is a shame for C programming on Windows.

Comment: Huh. Do you know why MS won't implement C99?

Comment: http://herbsutter.com/2012/05/03/reader-qa-what-about-vc-and-c99/

As I understand it, they will only implement features that are subset of the C++ standards.

Comment: @kunkelwe: Because Microsoft's only involvement in the C standards process is to sabotage it.

Comment: Not really. There are still C99 implementations for Windows.

Comment: @JohnBode You're ten years too late to be seen as trendy when turning the topic from the suckth of Linux (GNOME, PulseAudio, etc) into the suckth of Windows (pre-SP2 Windows XP).

Answer (score 6):

The only remotely-relevant "C compiler" that could be used for desktop-application or mobile-application usage but which does not support C99 is MSVC. If you're writing embedded software for obscure systems with their own proprietary compilers, avoiding C99 features might make sense, but the choice in Gnome makes no sense at all.